# Looking to identify sci-fi magazines/comics from the 60s and 70s

Tags: story-identification, comics

Maybe someone can help me identify the mags/comics I came across written in the 1960s or 1970s. There were a couple stories in comic book format:

1) One was about a kid receiving a radio signal from an alien space ship. He alerts the military and it becomes a media circus and vendors and hot dog sellers all show up. As they are about to land, they land in some hot lava and are destroyed by giant rocks, and it turns out their ship was minuscule and landed in a hot dog and were eaten by the general.

2) Another was about two couples having Thanksgiving dinner and musing on how humans might just be a form of livestock. This turns out to be true and one of the attendees is "harvested" and the others are "mind-wiped" and do not realize she is taken even while it is happening.

Been telling my kids about this for years, but can't track down those older comics. They were in black and white (no color) and were a smaller format, about 6-8" in size. They were not in actual comic-book format, but reminded me of the older pulp mags.

Comment: Were they in the same books?

Comment: Rather *Twilight Zone* sort of plots, but I don't recall those specific stories.  TZ did run a comic for a while, which I didn't read; these might be from that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Story #1 seems to be "Chewed Out" from [Weird Science, Vol 1 #12](https://eccomics.fandom.com/wiki/Weird_Science_Vol_1_12):

> Herold Setiker has made contact with aliens who he directs to earth. However they report landing in a murky lake which contain acid are being attacked by giant white monsters. The general arrests Herold but finds the pebble he feels in his mouth is actually the space ship.

I'm not a comic expert by any means, but based on my faulty memory I believe that older comics were occasionally reprinted in black and white digest format, so perhaps that's where you read it.

Comment: That sounds very much like it. Thanks so much. I'll see if I can dig up some older copies of Weird Science.

Comment: Happy to help, though I'm completely stumped on the second one.

Comment: "Spaceship landing in murk"... something sufficiently similar to suggest the same author was in (I think) one of the "Spectrum" Amis/Conquest anthologies. A central element was that the inhabitants on the ship moved and communicated vastly faster than humans, but that was overlooked until the end when the visiting ship had landed in long grass and the man who's fallen for a girl arriving in it remarks "we're going to need a magnifying glass".